# "Practise" vs. "practice"

Tags: british-english, orthography, se-ce

As an Australian, I like to follow British forms of words such as *license/licence* and *practise/practice*. I have no problem with *licence* the noun and *license* the verb, but I find it hard to keep *practise* and *practice* straight.

To get better, I *practise* my juggling. When I see a doctor, I visit their *practice*. But what about preparing a set of *practice problems*? Are they a set of problems that are used for *practising*, being instead *practise problems*? Is there a use of the word *practice* besides referring to, say, a doctor's establishment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The use of *practice* in *practice problems* is correct. Here, *practice problems* is a compound noun with *problems* modified by *practice*. It means *problems used for practice*.

It helps your understanding to replace *practice* here with *revision*. We use *revision problems*, not *revise problems*, to mean *problems used for revision*. *Practice* is simply a noun meaning *the act of practising*, just like *revision* is a noun meaning *the act of revising*.

Comment: I do not think that it should be 'practice', even using the 'revise' example.  Notice the example cited; "To get better, I ‘practise’ my juggling."  It could also be (somewhat incorrectly) written as; "To get better, I ‘revise’ my juggling."  However, it could not be written; "To get better, I ‘consulting rooms’ my juggling."

Comment: @RichieACC: Are you saying you'd write "revise problems" (with the verb) rather than "revision problems" (with the noun)? Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps my comment makes less sense than the answer which I also submitted.  It would most certainly be "revision problems".

Comment: I always use *advice/advise* as an example to help explain this one; since they sound different, it's easier for people to remember the difference. In your example, you'd use 'advice problems', not 'advise problems'.

Comment: 'lack of practice' or 'lack of practise'? please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

Either "practice" or "practise" in British dialects of English may be used for the verb form (see the OED - it merely lists them as alternate spellings). The OED also lists "practise" as a variant for the noun, although it is pretty clear that "practice" is preferred for the noun form.

For example, I hold a practising certificate, which allows me to practise (or practice) as part of a solicitors' practice.

Answer (score -4):

I think that the correct one to use would be 'practise'.  A test that I use would be to replace the words with similar words or phrases.  'Practise' means to perform repetitions of an action in order to perfect it, or to exercise a current ability.  While 'practice' is a doctor's consulting room.

So in your examples, you could say, "To get better, I ‘exercise’ my juggling." Or, "When I see a doctor, I visit their ‘consulting rooms’."

You could refer to 'exercise problems', but you could not refer to 'consulting room problems'.

Comment: This is wrong: in standard British English, [practise](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/practise_1?q=practise) is a verb, and [practice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/practice_3) is the corresponding noun. You are right that *practice* can mean a doctor's work (and, by extension, his place of work - his consulting rooms), but this is because he *practises* medicine (and therefore is work is *practice*).